# create a chart (google charts and jquery.csv) by sorting rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, csv, google-visualization

This is my first post here.

I am new to java and google charts. I have been playing around with google charts and "reading" csv files. My question is: Is it possible to sort out specific rows from a csv file and plot a line-chart with values from same rows but different columns?

For example, I would like to plot r1 on x-axis and r2 on y-axis for only the month of Jan. see files below. Perhaps I have been doing it all wrong, so any help is appreciated.

the csv:

```
month,year,r1,r2,r3
dec,1,0.1,0.34,0.55
dec,1,0.25,0.15,0.45
jan,1,0.3,0.1,0
jan,1,0.31,0.1,0.55
jan,2,0.35,0.56,0.45
jan,2,0.36,0.25,0.34
jan,2,0.4,1,0.15
jan,5,0.45,0.56,0.1
apr,5,0.34,0.26,0.15
apr,5,0.15,0,0.1
apr,5,0.1,0.15,0.1
dec,2,0.1,0.1,0.56
dec,2,0.56,0.1,0.25
jan,2,0.5,0.56,1
jan,1,0.6,0.23,0
apr,1,0.1,0.55,0.55
dec,5,0.1,0.45,0.45
```

the html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Aldins Example</title>

</head>
<body>

<div id="chart" style="width:600px; height:400px;"></div>
    <ul>

        <li>Y-values<select class="chart" id="yrange"></select></li>
        <li>X-values<select class="chart" id="xrange"></select></li>

    </ul>

<script src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.csv-0.71.js"></script>
<script>

    // load the visualization library from Google and set a listener
    google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    function drawChart() {

        // grab the CSV
        thecsvfile = "data/data2.csv"

        $.get(thecsvfile, function(csvString) {

            // transform the CSV string into a 2-dimensional array
            var arrayData = $.csv.toArrays(csvString, {onParseValue: $.csv.hooks.castToScalar});

            // use arrayData to load the select elements with the appropriate options
            for (var i = 0; i < arrayData[0].length; i++) {
                //* this adds the given option to both select elements
                 $("select").append("<option value='" + i + "'>" + arrayData[0][i] + "</option");
            }

            // set the default selection
            $("#xrange option[value='0']").attr("selected","selected");
            $("#yrange option[value='1']").attr("selected","selected");
            $("domain option[value='3']").attr("selected","selected");

            // this new DataTable object holds all the data
            var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(arrayData);

            // this view can select a subset of the data at a time
            var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
            view.setColumns([0,1]);


            var options = {
                title: "Title",
                hAxis: {title: data.getColumnLabel(0), minValue: data.getColumnRange(0).min, maxValue: data.getColumnRange(0).max},
                   vAxis: {title: data.getColumnLabel(1), minValue: data.getColumnRange(1).min, maxValue: data.getColumnRange(1).max},
                   legend: 'none'
            };

            var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart'));
            chart.draw(view, options);



            // set listener for the update button
            $("select").click(function(){

                // determine selected domain and range
                var xrange = +$("#xrange option:selected").val();
                var yrange = +$("#yrange option:selected").val();
                var domain = +$("#domain option:selected").val();


                // update the view
                view.setColumns([yrange,xrange]);

                // update the options
                options.hAxis.title = data.getColumnLabel(xrange);
                options.hAxis.minValue = data.getColumnRange(xrange).min;
                options.hAxis.maxValue = data.getColumnRange(xrange).max;
                options.vAxis.title = data.getColumnLabel(yrange);
                options.vAxis.minValue = data.getColumnRange(yrange).min;
                options.vAxis.maxValue = data.getColumnRange(yrange).max;

                // update the chart
                chart.draw(view, options);
            });

        });
    }
</script>    


</body>
</html>
```

the [jguery.csv-0.71.js](http://www.aldindelic.se/test/jquery.csv-0.71.js)

Comment: Are you looking for a method of allowing the user to filter by month, or just have the data filtered by some fixed value?

Comment: Filter by month. However one should be able to choose the month by selecting it from a menu. Just like I have it for the x- and y-values. For example *<select id="month"></select>*

Comment: Would a [CategoryFilter](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/controls#categoryfilter) work for you?